# On my android device, superuser and normal user see different /sdcard folder

Tags: android

On my android device, superuser and normal user see different /sdcard folder. In details, when I login as a normal user, in the /sdcard folder, I can see many files. However, when I login as a superuser, in the /sdcard folder, I can only see a single file. I am confused about this observation. Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: It might be because of the Linux permissions, but it is still weird that the superuser sees less than the normal user. https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using SuperSU?
If yes, please disable namespace trimming (or similar) in the settings.
You may have the pro version for that. If you don't want to buy it, enable Freeload.

Also which android version do you have?

Comment: Yes，I am using SuperSU.  I will have a try. Thank  you. In additional, my android version is 5.1.1 (LMY48I). I notice that there are another two android versions which have the same version numbers, namely, 5.1.1 (LMY48B) and 5.1.1 (LMY48M). Do you know their differences?

Comment: That is only the revision of the version.

Comment: You method works!!!!!! But what is Freeload? I cannot find it in the setting of SuperSU. Additionally, do other android version have namespace mechanisms?

Comment: Freeload is to enable the pro version without to pay for it. You can find it at the very bottom of the settings. Thank you for your feedback! I always disable namespace trimming because it causes issues with some apps. Good to know!

Comment: Exactly, I debug an existing app that causes issues because of the namespace problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. You don't have to worry about other apps. If you enable the option normally ALL apps work.